# Nodejs Mysql callback in callback

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, callback

Hello I'm stuck in my first callback "selectArticleByTitle(title, callback)", the terminal send "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined". I don't know how to force the first callback to finish this and launch the others.

```
 router.get('/article/:title', function(req, res){
    dataBase.selectArticleByTitle(req.params.title, function(db_titleERR, db_titleResults){
      console.log(db_titleResults);
      dataBase.selectArticle(db_titleResults[0].id, function(db_resultsArticleERR, db_resultsArticle) {
        //Get id of the previous article
        dataBase.previousArticle(db_titleResults[0].id, function(db_previousIdERR, db_previousId){
          //Get id of the next article
          dataBase.nextArticle(db_titleResults[0].id, function(db_nextIdERR, db_nextId){
            //Get lastArticle
            dataBase.lastArticle(function(db_lastArticleERR, db_lastArticle) {
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
});



exports.selectArticleByTitle = function(title, callback){
  connection.query('select * from article where title=?', [title], function(err, row){
    if(err)
      callback(err, null);
    else{
      if(row){
        callback(null, row);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Here the log
console.log(db_titleResults);

[ RowDataPacket {
    id: 7,
    genre: 'Sciences',
    picture: 'xw',
    source: 'xswx',
    title: 'zzazzaz',
    meta: 'azazadsq',
    inputDate: 2017-04-15T10:00:00.000Z,
    visitor: 0 } ]
[]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Try to print out the contents of row to help see what you are being returned.   `console.log(row);`

Comment: Ok, I edited my post.

Comment: Unfortunately, although it's definitely not the best solution, you could engage in what the industry calls _callback hell_ where you wait on one callback to finish before engaging in another. I'm interested to see what the other solutions are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with the original code then try the below...

The issue is that you are being returned one row. However you are trying to access the result as if there are many rows being returned in an array.

The below should at least get rid of your error. I would recommend to check the length of the results as well. if `db_titleResults.length` is defined then you know sql returned an array.

Instead of `db_titleResults[0].id`, you should use `db_titleResults.id`.

```
 router.get('/article/:title', function(req, res){
    dataBase.selectArticleByTitle(req.params.title, function(db_titleERR, db_titleResults){
      console.log(db_titleResults);
      dataBase.selectArticle(db_titleResults.id, function(db_resultsArticleERR, db_resultsArticle) {
        //Get id of the previous article
        dataBase.previousArticle(db_titleResults.id, function(db_previousIdERR, db_previousId){
          //Get id of the next article
          dataBase.nextArticle(db_titleResults.id, function(db_nextIdERR, db_nextId){
            //Get lastArticle
            dataBase.lastArticle(function(db_lastArticleERR, db_lastArticle) {
              });
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
});
```

I am not sure what library you are using to connect to sql but can avoid nested call backs with an approach like below:

```
const sql = require('mssql')
sql.connect(config, err => {
    // ... error checks

    const request = new sql.Request()
    request.stream = true // You can set streaming differently for each request
    request.query('select * from article where title=?', [title])

    request.on('row', row => {
        // Emitted for each row in a recordset
        dataBase.selectArticle(row.id, ...);
        dataBase.previousArticle(row.id, ...);
        dataBase.lastArticle(row.id, ...);
    });

    request.on('error', err => {
        // May be emitted multiple times
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I'm using mysql module.